# JQuery UI Autcomplete in Rails app almost working, but I can't navigate or click on the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, coffeescript

I'm trying to get the JQuery UI autocomplete widget to work with my Rails app. In my .js.coffee file for the controller, I have

```
$ ->
    $('#category_form').autocomplete( {source: category_array} )
```

When I load the page and start typing into the #category_form field the menu of autocomplete possibilities appears, but it disappears if I try and navigate through it with the arrow keys, or click on it with the mouse.

When I inspect the html of the page, it's clear that the widget is doing something. For instance if there are three autocomplete possibilities, the html looks like this

```
<input id="category_form" name="service[category]" placeholder="Service category..."
size="30" type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
3 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.
</span>
```

At first I was alarmed by the appearance of autocomplete="off", but this is also true of the working examples online. Despite the message in the span, using the up and down arrow keys just causes the menu of possibilities to vanish.

I've been searching around for a while, but I haven't found anyone else with this exact problem. Can anybody help me figure out what's going on here?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem. The problem was that I had both the .css and the .min.css files in my stylesheets folder. I'm pretty sure the style rules were colliding and as a result broke the autocomplete widget. I got rid of the .css file and the problem went away. Hopefully, this will help anyone out who runs into the same problem.